# why is the Catch exception e printing instead of doing what is in Try

Tags: java, error-handling, try-catch

I am confused why it is going to catch and print the error occurred message when I run my code since it runs and just prints the message I can't tell what the error could be

Note: this is my very first time using try and catch my professor told us to use it but haven't really learned how it works fully yet so I'm not sure if the problem is with that or if it's just with my code

```
public static void main (String [] args) {
    try {
        File file = new File("in.txt");
        Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(file);
        ...
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
}
```

Comment: `Exception` is just another class, and `e` is just an instance of `Exception` (or probably a sbuclass of `Exception`).  So `e` will have methods available (see the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/Exception.html)).  For example, try changing `System.out.println("Error occured...");` to `System.out.println(e.getMessage());`.

Comment: now null printed out

Answer (score 0):

Do not catch an exception unless you know what to do. It is common that you don't - most exceptions aren't 'recoverable'.

So, what do you do instead?

1. Simplest plan: Just tack `throws Exception` on your `main` method. `public static  void main(String[] args)` methods should by default be declared to `throws Exception`, you need a pretty good reason if you want to deviate from this.
2. Outside of the `main` method, think about your method. Is the fact that it throws an exception an implementation detail (a detail that someone just reading about what the method is for would be a bit surprised by, or which could change tomorrow if you decide to rewrite the code to do the same thing but in a different way)? In that case, do *not* add that exception to the `throws` clause of your method. But if it is, just add it. Example: Any method whose very name suggests that file I/O is involved (e.g. a method called `readFile`), should definitely be declared to `throws IOException`. It'd be weird for that method *not* to throws that.
3. Occasionally you can't do that, for example because you're overriding or implementing a method from an interface or superclass that doesn't let you do this. Or, it's an implementation detail (as per 2). The usual solution then is to just catch it and rethrow it, wrapped into something else. Simplest:

```java
} catch (IOException e) {
  throw new RuntimeException("uncaught", e);
}
```

Note that the above is just the best default, but it's still pretty ugly. `RuntimeException` says very little and is not really catchable (it's too broad), but if you don't really understand what the exception means and don't want to worry about it, the above is the correct fire-and-forget. If you're using an IDE, it probably defaults to `e.printStackTrace()` which is really bad, fix that template immediately (print half the details, toss the rest in the garbage, then just keep on going? That's.. nuts).

Of course, if you know exactly why that exception is thrown and you know what to do about it, then.. just do that. Example of this last thing:

```
public int askForInt(String prompt) {
  while (true) {
    System.out.println(prompt + ": ");
    try {
      return scanner.nextInt();
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
      System.out.println("-- Please enter an integral number");
    }
  }
}
```

The above code will catch the problem of the user not entering an integer and knows what to do: Re-start the loop and ask them again, until they do it right.

Just add `throws Exception` to your `main` method declaration, and toss the try/catch stuff out.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with your current code:

```
catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error occured...");
}
```

Firstly, you are not printing any information about the exception that you caught.  The following would be better:

```
catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());  // prints just the message
}

catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);  // prints the exception class and message
}

catch (Exception e) {
    e.getStackTrace(System.out);  // prints the exception stacktrace
}
```

Secondly, for a production quality you probably should be *logging* the exceptions rather than just writing diagnostics to standard output.

Finally, it is usually a bad idea to catch `Exception`.  It is usually better to catch the exceptions that you are expecting, and allow all others to propagate.

You could also declare the `main` method as `throws Exception` and don't bother to catch it.  By default, JVM will automatically produce a stacktrace for any uncaught exceptions in `main`.  However, that is a lazy solution.  And it has the disadvantage that the compiler won't tell you about checked exceptions that you haven't handled.  (That is a bad thing, depending on your POV.)

---

> now null printed out.

This is why the 2nd and 3rd alternatives are better.  There are some exceptions that are created with `null` messages.  (My guess is that it is a `NullPointerException`.  You will need a stacktrace to work out what caused that.)

Answer (score -2):

Catching `Exception e` is often overly broad. Java has many built-in exceptions, and a generic `Exception` will catch all of them. Alternatively, consider using multiple `catch` blocks to dictate how your program should handle the individual exceptions you expect to encounter.

```
catch (ArithmeticException e) {
    // How your program should handle an ArithmeticException
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    // How your program should handle a NullPointerException
}
```

Comment: While you have a valid point that catching `Exception` can be problematic (though you don't really explain why), catching unexpected `ArithmeticException` or `NullPointerException` specifically is a bad idea too.  An unexpected runtime exception should most likely not be handled / recovered from at all.  It leads to evidence of real bugs being overlooked or discarded, and new bugs that are caused by incorrect recovery from exceptions that are not really recoverable.

Comment: And if `ArithmeticException` or `NullPointerException` are *expected* exceptions, then there is something very wrong with your application code.